# A Swing component to display separate, selectable strings on different lines?

Tags: java, swing, textbox

I'm looking for a Swing component that displays several separate strings (probably from a string array or list) on separate lines within a pane or field (scrollable if there's too many to show at once). The user needs to be able to select one of these lines (double-clicking would be ideal) and thereby trigger a listener that does some magic with that line's string. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a JList: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html. Can be added to a ScrollPane if you want to include scrolling ability.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use a [JList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) inside a vertical JScrollPane.

Answer (score 1):

> The user needs to be able to select one of these lines (double-clicking would be ideal) and thereby trigger a listener that does some magic with that line's string

You can use the [List Action](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/14/list-action/) for this.